# Where can I find the terminal on a MacBook Air 2011

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm using a borrowed laptop- a MacBook Air 2011- and have no idea where to find the terminal. It's not in Applications, or the side bar...

Comment: You can find Terminal in the Utilities folder within the Applications folder. Alternatively you can use Spotlight and search for Terminal app. You can find spotlight in the top right corner of the menu bar that looks like a magnifying glass.

Comment: That looks like an answer to me, @AVelj Why not put it in the answer space, rather than comments.

Comment: @Tetsujin true, but it's not worthy of a proper answer without me including images and properly formatting my answer. Don't have too much time to do all that right now. I like to be thorough when writing answers.

Comment: The great thing about a quick answer is anyone can edit in images later or make them better if needed. Comments, like this can’t be built upon and hence, go away quickly...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, spotlight should find all apps (command space) if you don’t know where they sit.

The terminal app is in **/Applications/Utilities**

Also, the help menu works if you search for terminal, it’s not the top hit, but you should see an article covering apps included with macOS. This user guide has links to open each app (including terminal.app) and very helpful summaries of what they do.